# App Store No Production Certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, ssl, app-store

I've been invited on an Apple Developer Account and tried to create a Production Certificate for Ad Hoc distribution but it seems that i can only create a certificate for Development.

[image]

While on the tutorial i followed, there is a section for Production as follow:

[image]

I am new to the distribution of iOS App and don't know how to have the production certificate! Did i miss some steps or maybe some permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your account role must be `admin` or `agent` to create distributing certificates. Ask team agent to change your role from `Member` to `Admin`

More details here..
https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

Comment: You welcome... if it answers your question please accept the answer. If you don't know how to accept see this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Yes i will, need to wait 6 minutes